# UDP Throughput Dramatically Lowered with MTU = 1500

Tags: linux, networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, udp, iperf3

I am using **iperf3 version 3.5** under RHEL 8.0 to test a 10 Gbps point-to-point Ethernet connection with **UDP**. I have the MTU on both the source and destination NICs set to **1500**.

I invoke **iperf3** as follows:

```
Server:
iperf3 -s -V --udp-counters-64bit --forceflush

Client:
iperf3 -u -V -b 0 --udp-counters-64bit -t 30 -c 192.168.0.1 --forceflush -l 1472
```

The UDP payload size of 1472 bytes is chosen to make the Ethernet payload size exactly equal to the MTU of **1500**. I have verified with **tcpdump** that I am not experiencing frame fragmentation.

**iperf3** reports about **5.8 Gbps** throughput. When I increase the MTU to **9000** (i.e., jumbo frames), the reported throughput jumps to about **9.4 Gbps**. (I am assuming **iperf3** reports payload rate (i.e., rate of useable data, excluding headers).)

The MTU alone can't account for this. Here's the theoretical payload rate I'd expect with an MTU of **1500**:

| Frame Portion | Size (bytes) |
| --- | --- |
| Ethernet Preamble | 7 |
| Ethernet Start Frame Delimiter | 1 |
| Ethernet Header | 14 |
| IP Header | 20 |
| UDP Header | 8 |
| UDP Payload | 1472 |
| Ethernet Trailer (frame check sequence) | 4 |
| Inter-Frame Gap | 12 |
| **TOTAL** | **1538** |

Fraction of a frame that is payload: 1472 / 1538 = 0.957087

Therefore, on a 10 GbE link with an MTU of **1500**, I'd expect a theoretical payload rate of **9.57087 Gbps**.

If the MTU were raised to **9000**, we'd have a UDP payload size of 8972 bytes, and a total size of 9038 bytes. Doing the same math as above, the theoretical payload rate would be **9.92698 Gbps**.

So, the MTU doesn't even come close to accounting for the actual, measured payload rate of **5.8 Gbps**.

In the MTU **1500** case (**5.8 Gbps**), **iperf3** reported the following CPU usage statistics:

```
CPU Utilization: local/sender 99.7% (6.8%u/92.9%s), remote/receiver 58.1% (5.8%u/52.3%s)
```

In the MTU **9000** case (**9.4 Gbps**), **iperf3** reported the following CPU usage statistics:

```
CPU Utilization: local/sender 99.8% (7.2%u/92.5%s), remote/receiver 56.7% (5.6%u/51.1%s)
```

What else might be causing this substantial loss in UDP throughput?

Comment: What's the CPU load percentage during your tests?

Comment: The package rate is also relevant and would (have to) be tremendously higher at lower MTU.

Comment: I have added CPU usage statistics to the original post and will show them in this comment as well:

In the MTU **1500** case (**5.8 Gbps**), **iperf3** reported the following CPU usage statistics:
CPU Utilization: local/sender 99.7% (6.8%u/92.9%s), remote/receiver 58.1% (5.8%u/52.3%s)

In the MTU **9000** case (**9.4 Gbps**), **iperf3** reported the following CPU usage  
 statistics:

CPU Utilization: local/sender 99.8% (7.2%u/92.5%s), remote/receiver 56.7% (5.6%u/51.1%s)

Comment: @Dave That's your answer: Your sender's CPU is pegged trying to send "just" ~1.1 million 9k-long packets per second, so it doesn't even stand a chance of hitting 6.5 million 1.5k-long pps (although it does seem to be getting a higher packet rate in the 1.5k case, probably because each packet is only about 1/6th the size). The 10Gbit era is when traditional Unix kernel network stacks started to show their age; sockets and mbufs couldn't keep up, and that's when we saw folks create DPDK/ANS for Linux, Netmap for FreeBSD, Skywalk for macOS. Try again with dpdk-iperf3.